# How to generate swagger file during maven build

Tags: apache-camel, swagger

Library camel-swagger-java expose swagger during runtime generated based on RestConfigurationDefinition.
Is it possible to generate a swagger file during a maven build?
The only possibility I've already found is to generate a swagger during JUnit test execution, when Spring context is running, which is clumsy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made a simple maven plugin which can be used for swagger generation during maven build. https://github.com/PavelKa/apache-camel-swagger-plugin